# Making a FAQ in android

Tags: android, listview, storage

I'm currently developing an app for android, and I want to make FAQ so I don't get all kinds of questions. What is the best thing to do?
I've created a list view already, but where do I store the questions and answers?
I hope you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to have static strings or dynamic so the FAQ questions and answers could be loaded from the web for example. If you wanted to use static strings it is rather simple java code to use it within a ListView. It really does depend on how you want the strings to be loaded, Internet or from within the app.

Comment: I want to use static data, so when I have everything in a xml file it is alright? Does that give the best performance?

Comment: Yeah that will be fine. Performance wise it does not depend so much on your strings as it does on how you have setup your app so don't worry about that. You would probably be better off with not using a ListView and using another way of displaying the strings such as TextViews. This will make sure your app, when loading that Activity/Fragment, it runs as fast as possible (without taking into effect GPU Overdraw but don't worry about that at first)